# Android Can't play this video

Tags: java, android

I set a CountDownTimer to my application after a specific time it start a new activity and play a video but application face to this error can't play this video
this is my code

```
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.VideoView;

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.video_show);

            VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            v.setVideoPath("/sdcard/vid.mp4");
            v.start();
            v.requestFocus();
        }
    }

log cat:
```

01-12 15:12:05.178: E/MediaPlayer(23763): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: try /mnt/sdcard/vid.mp4

Comment: not working this for me

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with giving path `v.setVideoPath("/sdcard/vid.mp4")`
the correct one is `videodir = new File("/storage/sdcard1/dirvideo");`